# Kubuntu 17.04 : Issue with DNS resolution in Firefox

Tags: networking, kubuntu, firefox, dns, 17.04

Did a fresh install of KUBUNTU 17.04 since Unity is about to die.

However having issues with wireless network connectivity.

Firefox doesn't connect with error "Server not found".
While CHROME connects.

Tried every solution in bug reports.

```
➜  ~ ls -la /etc/resolv.conf            
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Apr 16 09:59 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`
```

nslookup works

Output of nmcli

```
➜  ~ nmcli device show wlp3s0 | grep IP4.DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.4.4
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
```

DNSMASQ is not installed.

Tried restarting NetwotkManager several times : KO

Answer (score 1):

Could be your router settings. In my case the same symptoms were caused by the Thomson cable modem's IP Flood Detection setting. Turned it off and Firefox started connecting as well as Chrome. The problems started with the upgrade to 17.04, never saw the errors with 16.10.

Answer (score 0):

Replace network manager to WICD, for me working good.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Could you please expand this answer a bit?  As it is, it's not very clear what the OP has to do.